# Generate forecasting value in C#using excel interop

Tags: c#, excel-formula, excel-interop

i want to generate forecasting value using excel introp forecast function. I need to used excel forecasting linear function but I want to store forecasting value to Database.

I dnt know how to start Please help me for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you need is a linear forecasting function, I think Excel Interop is probably overkill.  You can add references to the Office COM libraries from your C# project and call the [`WorksheetFunction.Forecast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.forecast(v=office.15).aspx) function, or you could just add a method to do the same thing in your C# code directly.  I think the linear forecast logic is essentially the following:

```
static double Forecast(double[] xValues, double[] yValues, double forecastPoint)
{
    var xAverage = xValues.Average();
    var yAverage = yValues.Average();

    var bounds = yValues
        .Select((y, i) => new { Value = y, Index = i })
        .Aggregate(new { Top = 0.0, Bottom = 0.0 }, (acc, cur) =>
            new
            {
                Top = acc.Top + (xValues[cur.Index] - xAverage) * (yValues[cur.Index] - yAverage),
                Bottom = acc.Bottom + Math.Pow(xValues[cur.Index] - xAverage, 2.0)
            });

    var level = bounds.Top / bounds.Bottom;

    return (yAverage - level * xAverage) + level * forecastPoint;
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply but i have one one 2 colums one is with value having Manufacturing YTD-1Y and one is Year

Comment: so how to get forcating from this

Comment: Pass the values for the Year column as the `xValues`parameter, the values for the Manufacturing YTD-1Y as the `yValues` parameter, and the year you  would like to forecast as the `forecastPoint` parameter.

Comment: @Tanmay, I've updated the example.  I often get the parameters to `Aggregate` backwards, as I'm used to `List.fold`.